# JDBC: Create tables on first use only?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am working on a Java UI application that uses JDBC.
I assume the database I'm working in is already existing. However, the tables the program refers to may not necessarily exist.

Thus, only on first use, I'd like to check if these tables exist, and if not, create them.

Comment: get connectionMetaData, query the tables, create the non-existing ones, alter the existing if new columns have been added, etc. Somehow risky stuff.

Comment: Or use an existing database migration library: I've had success with [LiquiBase](http://liquibase.org/) with a moderately complex scenario, [FlyWay](https://code.google.com/p/flyway/) might be decent too.

Comment: try altering table w/ 100m+ rows that has some indexes too, it (might) take(s) awful amount of time even if you get all your code right. If there is an error in you code - say a cornet case, the data can be "lost". also due to the non-standard SQL (create/alter table) the result might become unpredictable amongst different databases or even versions of a certain database.

Comment: That certainly isn't too reassuring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While creating table say

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ......
```

See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) for more information.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee (id INT);
```

This works with [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html), [sql](http://mckoi.com/database/SQLSyntax.html), [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-createtable.html), [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/create-table.html)

Comment: Note that not all databases implements this functionnality.

Comment: Oracle Database, by the way, "sql" is not a database, and the link you gave is about Mckoi SQL db

Comment: @alain.janinm : ***[what is this then??](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/create-table.html)***

Comment: actually that looks like an Oracle MySQL implementation guide, check out the root of the URL (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/).  Oracle SQL does not support it.

Comment: Alright, I'm confused. Does this work? Or should I be looking for another answer?

Comment: go for it if your DBMS supports it - it's definitely the most straightforward

Comment: I'm using MySQL, so from the comments above, it works. But it'd be interesting to have an implementation that works across all DMBS's. In case I want to change DBMS for whatever reason.

Comment: Falhim, adding extra question marks doesn't add credibility to the question. Sybase do not support it for sure. Oracle doesn't not support ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7002.htm ). I am not even an expert it's not standard at all, though. So you can say at least the top 2 enterprise DBs do not support.

Comment: The link you provide is for MySQL, goodness that's pure ignorance.